# AWS CLI save output as log file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm new to AWS CLI (and programming), but I've looked through documentation and posted questions and can't find this addressed, I must be missing something basic?

How do I save the output?  I'd like to run AWS S3 Sync to backup my data overnight, and I'd like to see a log report in the morning of what happened.

At this point, I can run AWS from a command prompt:

```
aws s3 sync "my local directory" s3://mybucket
```

I've set output format to Text in the config.  But I'm only seeing the text in the command prompt.  How can I export it as a log file?

Is this not possible, what am I missing?

Many thanks in advance,
Matthew

Comment: Well I figured it out.  I just added >C:\Logs\MyLogName.txt to the end of the command.

Comment: You should mark your question as answered

Answer (score 6):

```
aws s3 sync "my local directory" s3://mybucket --debug 2> "local path\logname.txt"
```

Comment: you have to put 2> in the command like this : aws s3 sync . s3://bucket --debug 2> log.txt

Comment: ¿Any thoughts on how to do this without the --debug? Using just ">" also puts in all the "Completed...remaining" lines. I tried to get rid of those by piping in through grep; however, because those lines use ^M carriage returns, grep doesn't work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Not only did I figure out adding > filename to the end of the command, but I also figured out that when saving this as a batch file, it won't run as a scheduled task in Windows Server 2008 r2, or Windows 7, if it contains drive mappings.  UNC paths are required.

Thanks! 
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

this perfectly worked for me

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name "stack name" --debug 2> "C:\Users\ravi\Desktop\CICDWORKFolder\RedshiftFolder\logname.txt"
```